# PUT request not passing HTML form data as object

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm having trouble passing an object through to my PUT route via an HTML form. When I try to console.log the 'product' object the terminal reads undefined. I've got Method Override installed and everything works fine if I don't try to pass the data as an object. e.g. name="title" and name="price".

app.js

```
router.put('/events/:id', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body.product);
   res.redirect('/events/');
});
```

HTML

```
<form action="/events/<%= product._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="product[title]" value="<%= product.title%>">
  </div>                
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="product[price]" value="<%= product.price%>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: oh! it was set to false. works now. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not correctly configuring `body-parser` since you can reach your middleware and print out something from there to your console. Just to make sure you have configured something like this:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
```

Then your app should correctly populate the input value to `req.body`.